# Should I put a downtube guard on my aluminium enduro bike?

Tags: frames, upgrade-or-new-bike, frame-protection

I am about to purchase a new Whyte G170s mountain bike. It does not come with a downtube protector to protect from rock strikes. Although the frame is not carbon I am wondering whether I should buy a guard or not. My last bike (a Trek Fuel) was also AL and came with a downtube guard included.

So should I get one or should my frame be OK with rock strikes?

Cheers.

Comment: Is there downside to fitting a guard?

Comment: Mud and rocks will not *damage your frame*, but over extended heavy use, they might scratch the paint a little. Certainly never hurts to get one, and (IMO) they look kinda neat.

Comment: It may improve resale if there aren't dings and scratches.

Comment: On a brand new, never-ridden frame, you will be extra-careful until your first biff / scratch.  Then its less important.   So either ride carefully forever, or go on a hard ride in the first couple days and get it over with.   Personally I'd look at the clear sticky tape used to keep things neat, but do it first before any riding.

Comment: You might want to consider something like helicopter tape to protect the paint.

Answer (score 2):

Carbon frames are strong, but when struck hard, they can crack, which is quite nasty. Aluminium frames just dent and rarely crack. Depending on how you ride and where you ride, a downtube protector may be something to consider. It's not necessarily for protecting the structural integrity of your frame since, you would probably need a rock the size of a small boulder to really ireversibly damage your frame. However, a downtube protector may be benificial for you to protect your paint from rock chips and scratches as a result of trail debris. Hope this helped!